# How can I use php file in Angular4?

Tags: php, angular, forms

How can I import and use my 'register.php' and 'dbConnect.php' files in angular 4 to use my register form on index.html?

Comment: Read https://angular.io/docs

Answer (score -1):

I would rather move the angular 4 content in index.html to index.PHP and include the other PHP files in the index.php

Answer (score -1):

Only way you can use php inside an angular app (basically just html + js) is in an iframe. Makes no sense though, recommend rewriting your form entirely in Angular and only using php as a backend which you call using XHR (HttpClient in Angular).

Answer (score -2):

You can try

```
<?php require 'register.php';?>
```

or

```
<?php include 'register.php';?>
```